# topology layers separation algorithm

Tags: c++, polygon

I have the following problem. Suppose you have a big array of Manhattan polygons on the plane (their sides are parallel to x or y axis). I need to find a polygons, placed closer than some value delta. The question -  is how to make this in most effective way, because the number of this polygons is very large. I will be glad if you will give me a reference to implemented solution, which will be easy to adapt for my case.

Comment: Can the polygons be concave? Self-intersecting? Do they contain holes?

Comment: What exaclty do you want to find? Pairs of polygons for which the closest distance between two points of them is shorter then delta? Or should you find all polygons participating in at least one such pair?

Comment: Polygons can be concave, but not self-intersecting. They don't contain holes. Polygons participating in at least one such pair. Sorry for uncertainty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is the sweep and prune algorithm (also known as sort and sweep).

Basically, you first find out the 'bounds' of each shape along each axis. For the x axis, these would be leftmost and rightmost points on a shape. For the y axis, the topmost and bottommost.

Lets say you have a bound structure that looks something like this:

```
struct Bound
{
    float value;      // The value of the bound, ie, the x or y coordinate.
    bool  isLower;    // True for a lower bound (leftmost point or bottommost point).
    int   shapeIndex; // The index (into your array of shapes) of the shape this bound is on.
};
```

Create two arrays of these Bounds, one for the x axis and one for the y.

```
Bound xBounds* = new Bound[2 * numberOfShapes];
Bound yBounds* = new Bound[2 * numberOfShapes];
```

You will also need two more arrays. An array that tracks on how many axes each pair of shapes is close to one another, and an array of candidate pairs.

```
int closeAxes* = new int[numberOfShapes * numberOfShapes];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShapes * numberOfShapes; i++)
    CloseAxes[i] = 0;

struct Pair
{
    int shapeIndexA;
    int shapeIndexB;
};

Pair candidatePairs* = new Pair[numberOfShapes * numberOfShape];
int numberOfPairs = 0;
```

Iterate through your list of shapes and fill the arrays appropriately, with one caveat:
Since you're checking for closeness rather than intersection, add delta to each upper bound.
Then sort each array by value, using whichever algorithm you like.

Next, do the following (and repeat for the Y axis):

```
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < 2 * numberOfShapes; i++)
{
    if (xBounds[i].isLower && xBounds[i + 1].isLower)
    {
        unsigned int L = xBounds[i].shapeIndex;
        unsigned int R = xBounds[i + 1].shapeIndex;

        closeAxes[L + R * numberOfShapes]++;
        closeAxes[R + L * numberOfShapes]++;

        if (closeAxes[L + R * numberOfShapes] == 2 ||
            closeAxes[R + L * numberOfShapes] == 2)
        {
            candidatePairs[numberOfPairs].shapeIndexA = L;
            candidatePairs[numberOfPairs].shapeIndexB = R;
            numberOfPairs++;
        }
    }
}
```

All the candidate pairs are less than delta apart on each axis. Now simply check each candidate pair to make sure they're actually less than delta apart. I won't go into exactly how to do that at the moment because, well, I haven't actually thought about it, but hopefully my answer will at least get you started. I suppose you could just check each pair of line segments and find the shortest x or y distance, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way to go about the 'narrow phase' step.

Obviously, the actual implementation of this algorithm can be a lot more sophisticated. My goal was to make the explanation clear and brief rather than elegant. Depending on the layout of your shapes and the sorting algorithm you use, a single run of this is approximately between O(n) and O(n log n) in terms of efficiency, as opposed to O(n^2) to check every pair of shapes.